# Binding a List<string> to gridview

Tags: asp.net

I have a simple `GridView` with a single column bound to a `List<string>`. I have `AutoGenerateColumns="true"` and the column header text I get is **Item**.

What's the best way to modify column header? It doesn't need to be set to `AutoGenerateColumns="true"`

Comment: If you are able to create the column yourself, you can set the Caption or HeaderText property of that column.

Comment: what would be the binding value for the data part, say to a label? Text='<%# Container.DataItem %>' doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="My Modified Header Text">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```